# Pi crashes and restarts when using Bluetooth under high workload

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm experiencing an issue when using Bluetooth on a Raspberry Pi:

The Pi crashes and restarts automatically when using Bluetooth. I can reproduce this behaviour when running the following commands:

Screen #1 `/usr/bin/hcitool -i hci0 lescan --duplicates`

Screen #2 `/usr/bin/hcidump -i hci0 --raw`

These two commands are using the Bluetooth interface. Now, when the Pi is experiencing more work load, it will randomly crash and restart after a short time. To emulate this, I can simply run the `yes` command in another screen to get the Pi working. In practice I want to run a Java Spring application that uses the Bluetooth interface. In that case the crashes appear less frequent, but are still common.

In `/var/log/syslog` you can see the following error messages:

```
May 30 12:28:19 pi kernel: [ 1529.456782] bt_err_ratelimited: 83 callbacks suppressed
May 30 12:28:19 pi kernel: [ 1529.456794] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:19 pi kernel: [ 1529.508220] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:19 pi kernel: [ 1529.557408] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:19 pi kernel: [ 1529.606791] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:20 pi kernel: [ 1529.707340] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:20 pi kernel: [ 1529.756778] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:20 pi kernel: [ 1529.808184] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:20 pi kernel: [ 1529.857370] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:20 pi kernel: [ 1529.906751] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
May 30 12:28:20 pi kernel: [ 1529.958166] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
```

These messages appear repeatedly, as long as Bluetooth is in use. When the Pi finally crashes, there is no additional error message. So far I have not been able to find either the origin or fix for these messages. Also, I am not entirely sure wether these errors show the cause of my problem or wether they are a side effect of what's happening somewhere else.

I appreciate any responses and thank you for your help!

Comment: There is [raspberrypi.se] site

Comment: You need to check your power supply's amper. Better if your power supply has greater than 2A.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds a bit like your power supply isn't capable enough. What Amps (A) or milliAmps (mA) are written on your power supply?